# Loading Text File Through ASPX Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

Ok I am working on a project using Web Pages. The Task is to load Text from a Text File and use it in a div. I used the ajax xmlhttprequest, the tutorial used in http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first. All is working fine, but the problem is the function is called when the button is clicked. But i want it to be called when the page loads. That is when the page is immediately opened. And I dont know how to use it. Here is my code:-

My Default.aspx File.....

```
    <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Project02._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script src="/Scripts/Dynamic.js"></script>
    <div id="Header"></div>




</asp:Content>



    function loadXMLDoc() {

    window.onload = loadXMLDoc;

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("Header").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("Header").innerHTML = loadXMLDoc;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:49683/Scripts/Content1.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Please Tell me how to code in here.
Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript needs to be wrapped in a script block. Also the window.load event needs to be outside the function declaration. Currently the function will never fire.

```
   <script type='text/javascript'> 
     window.onload = loadXMLDoc;
    function loadXMLDoc() {

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("Header").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("Header").innerHTML = loadXMLDoc;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:49683/Scripts/Content1.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
    </script>
```

Comment: Also remove the .innerHTML = loadXMLDoc line.